# Does Gitorious have hooks for CIA commit notification?

Tags: git, hook, commit, gitorious

As I am running out of my space on [GitHub](http://github.com) on my free account (yes, I am considering upgrading), I am setting up new [git](http://git-scm.com/) repositories on Gitorious (see also [GitHub vs Gitorious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78991/why-is-github-more-popular-than-gitorious)). One great feature of GitHub is the post-commit hooks, that allow me to notify the (also great) [CIA network](http://cia.vc/)...

However, I have been unable to find if Gitorious supports such hooks... So, I'd like to ask best practices for getting commit messages show up on the CIA network for Gitorious-hosted git repositories.

**Update**: the solution of using a secondary mechanism to trigger CIA commit messages is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Also found it asked on a google group, but without answer: http://groups.google.com/group/gitorious/browse_thread/thread/3cf48f0f8631cf8a

Comment: KDE is also struggling with the same questions, and seemed to have made a custom solution: http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/MovetoGit#Post_Update_hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing straight to Gitorious, push to a local repository that you've configured (in its post-receive hook) to both push everything to your Gitorious repository and notify CIA.

Comment: How would I configure that local repository?

Comment: Put your CIA notification in the update hook (@maxy put a link: http://cia.vc/clients/git/ciabot.bash).  In the post-update hook, put a "git push --mirror Gitorious/url" (or git push --all, whichever is more appropriate)

Answer (score 5):

Gitorious is getting web hook support. It is currently running on gitorious.org, but without a UI for adding them to your repository; the reason for this is that there still may be a change or two to the JSON representation of the commit data exposed, so it should be configured a beta feature.

Anyone feeling up to writing integration code (handling gitorious' web hook requests), please send an email to support at gitorious.org and we'll set up the integration for your repository

Comment: Could you please add some URLs to further info on this hook support?

Comment: An example (and history) of the JSON payload generated is at http://www.postbin.org/wqpx3l

Comment: That was March, 2010. It's now 2012, and I still don't see such a feature!

Answer (score 3):

The KDE project had a similar question in [that thread](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/ifecyivQsROyQj3ZDKLV), with an interesting alternative:

> It doesn't have to be running *on* `gitorious.org` machines. At least, not 
>   for email/CIA/RSS/whatever reporting
>
> That's how our old `git-p4` hook worked in the office:
>   the p4 machine sent out a `UDP` packet with the revision number. Another machine caught it and did the import. (the value was discarded)
>
> We could do the same:
>
> - the `gitorious.org` machine sends a `UDP` packet with 
>     the branches that changed and their new `SHA-1`.
> - Another machine fetches and produces the commit logs.
>     Worst case scenario is that someone is forgotten due to a dropped `UDP` packet.
>
> Like I said, this works for reporting -- for anything that is run by a 
>   `post-receive` hook.
>   For anything requiring a `pre-receive` hook (actually, `pre-update`, but the name is wrong in Git), it will have to be run on their servers.

Comment: Who is 'you' in your comment?

Comment: @Egon: sorry, that was a first incorrect edit in my initial answer. I meant the KDE project.

Answer (score 2):

My current workaround is to set up a loal repository (called CIA) and always push via a tiny shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
git push origin master
git push cia master
```

In the local CIA repository I installed http://cia.vc/clients/git/ciabot.bash to send emails to the CIA.

Comment: I guess the first push should be a pull?

Comment: no, I always push the same commits to two different repository, the gitorious one (origin) which is where I want my code, and my local one (CIA) that will send the emails when I push

Answer (score 1):

Gitorious supports "Web Hooks": http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/WebHooks

It's a bit more effort, as it requires you to have a web server set up to receive the hook API calls.